# Is there a way to convert a given table to another table in excel/google sheets using a combination of formulas? as the example in the below images

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

FROM THIS[TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMgZB.png) TO
THIS [TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa8j9.png)

I tried to generate formulas for the same using chatgpt, but the results were not apt.

Comment: You should post what ChatGPT suggested, so we can have a laugh. :)

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
={"Village","Class","Team";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    QUERY(
      SPLIT(
        TOCOL(
          TOCOL(TOCOL(A2:A,3)&"ζ"&B1:C1)&"ζ"&
          MAP(TOCOL(B2:C,3),LAMBDA(n,SEQUENCE(1,n)))),
        "ζ"),
      "where Col3 is not null"))}
```

[image]

This formula is a variation of the [standard unpivoting formula](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/unpivot-in-google-sheets/).

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,wraprows(,3,),
     Λ,reduce(Σ,sequence(counta(A2:A)),lambda(a,c,{a;
             reduce(Σ,sequence(counta(B1:C1)),lambda(x,y,{x;index(if(sequence(index(B2:C,c,y)),{index(A2:A,c),index(B1:C1,y)})),sequence(index(B2:C,c,y))}))})),
     filter(Λ,index(Λ,,1)<>""))
```

[image]

***Updated Answer***:

```
=let(Σ,wraprows(,3,),
     Λ,reduce(Σ,sequence(counta(I2:I)),lambda(a,c,{a;
             reduce(Σ,sequence(counta(J1:K1)),lambda(x,y,{x;iferror(index(if(sequence(index(J2:K,c,y)),{index(A2:A,c),index(J1:K1,y)})),wraprows(,2,)),iferror(sequence(index(J2:K,c,y)),wraprows(,1,))}))})),
     filter(Λ,index(Λ,,1)<>""))
```

Comment: hi @rockinfreakshow if there is a zero( 0 ) or blank cell, in either class 4 or class 5 column it throws an error saying --Error
No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.--, can you help me pls.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with test data and expected output(manually entered) so as to get a clear picture to work it out

Comment: yes here it is...
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qq6LyFV0CVQpCVIcAla1uuZadZPJAPwtOvzhOYQ8YrE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've added an updated answer for you to test out.